# If I delete an episode from my iPhone, will it still be available on iTunes?

Tags: ios, iphone, itunes-store

I want to delete an episode from my iPhone so I can watch a different episode (because I took up so much space with music and such).  If I do, it won't permanently delete, will it?   Will it still be on the iTunes account, but not on this device?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on two things:

1. If you have a computer or another device set to automatically download purchases, you will have that copy as long as it is online and the download completes successfully.
2. If your account is [in a country that allows TV eposides to be re-downloaded](http://www.apple.com/ios/feature-availability/) (usually called [iTunes in the cloud](http://www.apple.com/icloud/features/itunes-in-the-cloud/)) you could re-download the episode later as long as the studio doesn't withdraw it from sale or download.